# ¿Porqué este procedimiento de sql server no devuelve lo que recibe en la entrada?

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo este ejemplo del que se espera que devuelva el mismo entero que recibe como parámetro además de que su retorno sea también dicho entero.
Lo estoy ejecutando en una instancia administrada de sql server en Azure, por si tiene algo que ver, aunque no lo creo.

```
    create PROCEDURE sp_A_test
       @InputValue int
    AS
    BEGIN
       DECLARE @sql               varchar(max);
       DECLARE @ParmDefinition    varchar(max);
       DECLARE @Result            int;

       set @sql = 'set @_Result = @_InputValue';
       SET @ParmDefinition = N'@_InputValue int, @_Result int output ';
       exec sp_executesql @sql, @ParmDefinition, 
                          @_InputValue = @InputValue,
                          @_Result = @Result;

       SELECT @Result AS Result;
       RETURN @Result;
    END
    GO
```

Sin embargo en "Result" devuelve NULL y retorna 0, con este mensaje de error:

```
Msg 214, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_executesql, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 2]
El procedimiento espera un parámetro '@statement' de tipo 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.
(1 row affected)
El procedimiento 'sp_A_test' intenta devolver como estado NULL, lo que no está permitido. Se devolverá en su lugar el estado 0.
```

¿Qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Creo que el error esta en que en los DECLARE estas definiendo varchar() y deberían ser nvarchar() y otra cosa pera retornar un valor cambia RETURN por la clausula OUTPUT para poder recibir el valor de @Result donde tu lo desees.

Comment: Gracias Stefan por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gracias al comentario de Stefan, di con la solución.
La pongo aquí por si a alguien más le sirve.

```
create PROCEDURE sp_A_test
   @InputValue int
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @sql               nvarchar(max);
   DECLARE @ParmDefinition    nvarchar(max);
   DECLARE @Result            int;

   set @sql = 'set @_Result = ISNULL(@_InputValue, 0)';
   SET @ParmDefinition = N'@_InputValue int, @_Result int output ';
   exec sp_executesql @sql, @ParmDefinition, 
                      @_InputValue = @InputValue,
                      @_Result = @Result OUTPUT;

   SELECT @Result AS Result;
   RETURN @Result;
END
GO
```

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).

Comment: Pero ¿qué es lo que hace este SP realmente y por qué mareas tanto tus variables y parámetros? Por favor [revisa la documentación](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/return-data-from-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver16) y trata de estandarizar tu código.

Comment: Creo que si os leéis la pregunta se ve bastante claro el propósito del código. En mi último mensaje publico el código corregido en base a los comentarios del compañero Stefan, y como indico, simplemente pongo la solución por si a alguien le sirve.